# Georgian Airways Flight Delay - Did LGW refuse flight and why?

Tags: air-traffic-control

Hi Our flight was delayed for 8 hours due to bad weather at Gatwick but there was no bad weather. I believe the airline was rejected by Gatwick due to a chance for holding if a storm came in. Is there a way to find out what ATC said to the airline???

Comment: ATC communication in the UK is not public: [Is it illegal for Joe Public to listen to ATC in the UK?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3264/is-it-illegal-for-joe-public-to-listen-to-atc-in-the-uk)

Comment: Also, could you add which flight this was (flight number, day)?

Comment: As @Bianfable says, you should provide more informations about your scheduled flight so that we can make our own research about this flight.

Comment: You may edit either the question or its title to be coherent (one is asking about listening ATC  communication and the other is about decision made by company or crew)

Answer (score 4):

Georgian Airways flight A9751 (Tbilisi to Gatwick) on the 19th of August indeed departed 7:30 hours late and arrived 7 hours late, according to FlightRadar24 records.

The exact cause of the delay is not public information. However, your theory that "ATC rejected the flight" seems highly improbable, since ATC can't actually do that. What could happen, is that flow control could impose ground delays to your flight to avoid airborne holdings later on if the capacity exceeds the demand. That could be the capacity at your destination, or at any of the countries your flight passes through on its way. So if, say, there were major thunder storms over Central Europe, a flight from Georgia to London might get caught up in that. However, 7:30 hour flow delays are almost unheard of, so that is probably not the (only) reason. My best bet would be technical or rostering issues, but that is only an educated guess.

If you really want to know the reason for delay, you should try contacting the airline