# Is there absolutely any way (hook or crook) to listen to ATC in India, especially Bangalore?

Tags: air-traffic-control, dgca-india

We can listen to various ATC radios across the world, but I really want to listen to the ATC at [VOBL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kempegowda_International_Airport).

Answer (score 7):

In principle you *can* listen to ATC of VOBL (Kempegowda International Airport, Bangalore) using a VHF air band radio receiver on the following frequencies:

- **Tower:** 124.35 MHz
- **Ground:** 121.65 MHz
- **Approach:** 121.25 and 127.75 MHz

It is however ***illegal*** to own such a receiver in India:

> 3. Prohibition of possession of wireless telegraphy apparatus
>      without licence.—Save as provided by section 4, **no person shall
>      possess wireless telegraphy apparatus** except under and in accordance
>      with a license issued under this Act.

<sup>([The Indian Wireless Telegraphy Act, 1933](https://www.wipo.int/edocs/lexdocs/laws/en/in/in037en.pdf), emphasis mine)</sup>

There used to be coverage of Mumbai ATC on [liveATC.net](https://www.liveatc.net/), but according to [this thread on pprune.org](https://www.pprune.org/south-asia-far-east/507393-mumbai-atc-now-available-liveatc-net.html) it was shut down, presumably because it is illegal to pass on ATC transmissions in India.

See also:

- [Is it illegal for Joe Public to listen to ATC in the UK?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3264/is-it-illegal-for-joe-public-to-listen-to-atc-in-the-uk?rq=1)

Comment: Surely other radio receivers are allowed to be owned by the general public though, such as an FM radio or UHF TV? What makes a radio that tunes to ~120 MHz special?

Comment: Receivers limited to only public spectrum operations would come with approval from some regulatory body (probably https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Planning_%26_Coordination_Wing) to be allowed for use without a license.  Other receivers would not be so approved.

Comment: I am not a lawyer anywhere, but it would seem that wireless telegraphy would imply transmission capabilities. alternatly, is a pilot's use of the frequency spectrum part of the certificate or is it tied to the station built into the airframe?

Comment: Yes -- why would this law apply to something incapable of transmitting?

Comment: Transmission is not a requirement of "wireless telegraphy apparatus", which is a term of art: *"wireless  telegraphy  apparatus’ means **any** apparatus, appliance, instrument or material **used or capable of use in wireless communication**, ..."* (emphasis added). "Wireless transmitter" is a specific and separate term, so clearly transmission capability was contemplated as a subset of wireless telegraphy.